# Where can I find unusual L-shaped brackets?

Tags: windows, hardware

I had windows installed in my gazebo, but had them installed with the screens on the outside and windows on the inside (for easier cleaning access).  My problem now is that strong winds blow the windows out!  I need some type of l-shaped brackets (72 of them), with a 3/16" short side and a 1" long side, in some shade of brown.  I need to have pre-drilled holes on the 1" side,  over half way toward the long end.  I've looked long and hard, with no success - can someone direct me to a resource for these, or do they not exist?

Comment: Wow - thanks, but...I  need the brackets to be real "L's":  one "leg" 3/16" and the other 1" - and I don't have a drill press.  Do you know of anything pre-made I could buy or have any other suggestions?  Or am I going to have to make them...which I can't...

Comment: Call your local welder and see if they can make them for you.  90's are usually uniform on both sides, anything else would be special order.  The steel shop will drill the holes where you want, cut to length and even paint them if you wanted.  You don't even need steel, you could use 1/8 inch aluminum ells which you could cut with a regular chop saw and drill yourself.

Comment: I have to say I have no clue what you are trying to do from reading your question. What type of windows (casement, double-hung, sliding, etc)? Pretty much all windows have an interior and an exterior side, and whether the screen is on the inside or outside depends on the style of window -- are you saying the window is installed backwards (eg, the exterior side is facing inside)? A picture would go a long way here.

Answer (score 3):

You could get a length of 1" x 1" x 1/8" angle steel, and manufacture your own.

[image]

Start by using a chop saw to cut the angle steel into pieces as wide as you need.

[image]

Next cut one side of the L to 3/16". A jig will help you cut the pieces quickly and accurately.

Use another jig to help you drill the holes.  A drill press with a carbide-tipped or cobalt drill bit will be useful for this.

[image]

Finally, paint the brackets to the desired color using a quality spray paint designed for metal.

Comment: I'll see if there are welders near me - my local window shop would make them, but wanted $6 each - since I need 72, that's a bit much.  Hopefully the welder will be cheaper.  And aluminum will do just fine for my purposes.  Thanks - Karen

Comment: Fantastic . A perfect DIY answer! I love it!